# Image won't be displayed on the screen flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter

i am trying to make an image appear on the screen but it just won't happen. i tried a lot of tutorials but none of them will work! it keeps telling me a bunch of errors like the image is not available for example. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoQI3.png)

Here is my code with all the files names:

Comment: Hey, please add your code to the question and not as an image. Also show us the error message you get. First step you can do: Check your pubspec file.

Comment: Hi, please also add the code for your pubspec.yaml, specifically the section where you declare your image as an asset.

Comment: please add pubspec.yaml file image or code

Answer (score 0):

Assets are usually kept on a separate folder outside libs. But since you kept it inside libs, add the following line to your pubspec.yaml file just below the `flutter:` section. It should look like this after you paste the code

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - lib/app_images/
```

this ensures that all the files inside the app_images folders are properly imported.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

- Replace your images with a new location it will help to solve the issue.

  ```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("AppMaking.co"),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue[900],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Image.asset(
          "images/app-making-name-logo.png",
          height: 200,
          width: 200,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  ```